# JointJS devs Port data disappaers when updating the graph from json

Tags: jointjs

I have some problem concering the fromJson and toJson method on the graph. When i download the json, my custom data attributes on the individual ports are also present in the json file. But when i try to upload it from the downloaded json, it totally resets and cleans my port options. Is there any way i can change this behaviour?

Thanks in advance,
Bende

Comment: Facing similar issue. Did anyone find solution?

Answer (score 2):

Was facing similiar issue.

In my case I was extending the **devs.Model** shape. It is a specific shape, which simplifies the current ports API by introducing inPorts and outPorts array attributes that held the ports.
Those were missing.

In order to fix the issue you should inherit from e.g. **basic.Generic** shape instead of devs.Model.

I changed from

```
return joint.shapes.devs.Model.extend({
    markup: [
    ].join(''),
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
        type: 'devs.GenericModel',
        attrs: {},
        ports: {},
    }, joint.shapes.devs.Model.prototype.defaults)
});
```

to

```
return joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend({
    markup: [
    ].join(''),
    defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
        type: 'devs.GenericModel',
        attrs: {},
        ports: {},
    }, joint.shapes.basic.Generic.prototype.defaults)
});
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem :)